# Groovy Spock Test case - inner method invocation

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, testcase

ApplicationController.groovy:

```
public class ApplicationController { 
    @Autowired
    ApplicationService applicationService

    public void executeMethodA(Map requestBody, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String result = applicationService.methodB('one','two')
    }
}
```

ApplicationService.groovy:

```
public class ApplicationService {  
    public String methodB(String arg1, String arg2) {
        String concatString = arg1.concat(arg2)
        return concatString 
    }
}
```

Spock Test case:

```
when:
applicationController.executeMehodA(requestBody, request, response)

then:
1 * applicationService.methodB('one','two') >> "onetwo"
```

Controller Method - executeMethodA
Service class method - methodB
We have mocked the Service class in the Controller Test class as:

```
ApplicationService applicationService = Mock(ApplicationService)
```

I have one method in the controller that calls a method in a service class, my Spock test case is passed.

ApplicationController.groovy:

```
public class ApplicationController { 
    @Autowired
    ApplicationService applicationService
    public void executeMethodA(Map requestBody, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String result = applicationService.methodC('one','two','three')
    }
}
```

ApplicationService.groovy:

```
public class ApplicationService {  
    public String methodB(String arg1, String arg2) {
        String concatString = arg1.concat(arg2)
        return concatString 
    }

    public String methodC(String d1, String d2, String d3) {
        String concatString = methodB(d1, d2)
        String finalString = methodB(concatString , d3)
        return finalString
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
when:
applicationController.executeMethodA(requestBody, request, response)
then:
1 * applicationService.methodC('one','two','three') >> "onetwothree"
```

When controller method is calling a method in service class, which in turn calls another method. 
We are getting an error that invocation is not matching as 1* or 0*

Tried using 1* as well as 0*. But I'm not getting any success

Error message:

**Too few invocations for:
1 * applicationService.methodC('one','two','three') >> "onetwothree"  (0 invocations)**

**Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
1 * applicationService.this$2$methodB('one', 'two')**

Need some guidance on how to write spock test cases that call a method from another

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  THe code above is invalid, which makes me suspect it's not the actual code you're trying

Comment: I agree with @tim_yates. The above code looks valid. The error message gives you a clue. MethodB is actually being called in your test. Is that expected? Not that it looks like it is being called from an anonymous object (like a closure, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can mock and spy the service in controller unit tests as below.

```
 1 * applicationService.invokeMethod("methodB", _) >> "onetwo"
```

Or

```
 1 * applicationService.invokeMethod(*_) >> { methodName, args ->
            assert methodName == "methodB"
            assert args[0] == "one"
            assert args[1] == "two"
            return "onetwo"
 }
```

Comment: Besides that using `invokeMethod` is not really a good idea and totally unnecessary, this answer does not at all have anything to do with OP question. His mocking of `methodB` worked, but the mocking of `methodC` did not work.